# The given selector is either invalid or does not result in a WebElement

Tags: selenium, firefox, xpath

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath(".//*[@id='reviewMetadata']/a']"));    
jse.executeScript("arguments [0],click();",element);
```

> Error: Exception in thread "main"
>   org.openqa.selenium.InvalidSelectorException: The given selector
>   .//*[@id='reviewMetadata']/a'] is either invalid or does not result in
>   a WebElement. The following error occurred: InvalidSelectorError:
>   Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression
>   .//*[@id='reviewMetadata']/a'] because of the following error:
>   SyntaxError: The expression is not a legal expression.

Comment: Add the relevant html

Comment: .//*[@id='reviewMetadata']/a

Comment: @muthubala I asked for the html, not your xpath

Comment: Your error message doesn't match up with the code provided. You need to spend some time trying a few things and then carefully document in your question what you tried and what the results were. You also need to post the relevant HTML or ideally a link to the page.

Answer (score 1):

You use extra quote after `a` element. You should use

```
".//*[@id='reviewMetadata']/a]"
```

Also replace comma with dot and remove space in

```
"arguments [0],click();"
```

to prevent following issues

Answer (score 0):

```
JavascriptExecutor jse = (JavascriptExecutor)driver;
WebElement element = driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='reviewMetadata']/a]"));    
jse.executeScript("arguments [0],click();",element);
```

Try replacing these lines and run. I guess you copied that `xpath` from `FirePath`. Don't forget to delete the full stop which is in the start of the `xpath`.

Comment: As i checked all the xpaths have . symbols . shall I remove all the full stops in program

Comment: Add `Firefinder` plugin in your FF browser to verify the `xpath` and `CSS selectors` before using them in your code.

Comment: did my answer helped you ?? @muthubala